# Ionic framework APK extended

Tags: ionic-framework, apk-expansion-files

I have built my hybrid app using Ionic Framework and got to the testing phase. I have gone to deploy with google play and found about the 50MB limit.

My app is 200MB and I have been told to split the app into an APK and APK extended.

Could anybody help me find out how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to get the base of your app below 100MB for the main APK file and then break out additional (likely media files) into expansion APK files.

There is a great plugin to then help with accessing this expansion content:
https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader